# Trouble loading image into GUI app, show white screen ? Kivy Python

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I'm having trouble loading my image into the GUI for Python using Kivy.All it shows is a white screen. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.image import Image 

class TheApp(App):
    def build(self):
        image = Image(source= "psychTREE.jpg")
        return image 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TheApp().run()
```

Comment: this works fine for me.  check your file and that it's in the same path.  the terminal output might give you a hint if it can't find the file or if there's a separate problem.